# @pnp/spfx-controls-react People Picker suggestions appearing behind modal - bug

Tags: spfx, pnp-js

I'm using https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/ on a fluent ui modal. When the user types in a person to search the suggestions appear behind the fluent ui modal, hiding it and making it near impossible to select a user.

I've found the suggestions element using the browser:
[image]

How would I target that element using css in conjunction with this control and maybe add a z-index:

```
  <PeoplePicker
     context={props.context}
     personSelectionLimit={10}
     defaultSelectedUsers={internalEmails && internalEmails.length > 0 ? internalEmails: []}
     showtooltip={true}
     onChange={(items) => setInternals(items)}
     // isRequired={true}
     showHiddenInUI={false}
     principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
     resolveDelay={1000}
   />
```

For info I'm using this version of the control: `"@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "3.16.0"`